# How can I install Unreal Tournament 4 (the latest) on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: games, 17.04

I followed [this guide on the Epic Games site](https://www.epicgames.com/unrealtournament/forums/unreal-tournament-development/ut-development-programming/linux/10281-how-do-i-install-ut4-on-linux),
which links to this: https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealTournament

which led me to this:
https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Building_On_Linux

and now I have Unreal Engine... not Unreal Tournament.

Update : this is the DL link : https://s3.amazonaws.com/unrealtournament/ShippedBuilds/%2B%2BUT%2BRelease-Next-CL-3525360/UnrealTournament-Client-XAN-3525360-Linux.zip

Comment: following this guide  : https://techpromad.wordpress.com/2016/04/24/run-unreal-engine-4-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: And how we are supposed to rename that? I think you should mail directly to the studio providing the engine and instructions and let them know of this, but here we cant do anything. And you can [edit] your question to include additional information.

Comment: now that you have the game engine installed. back up and install the game.

Comment: how do I do that? i ran `make UE4Editor UE4Game UnrealPak CrashReportClient ShaderCompileWorker UnrealLightmass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using this guide worked for me :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_4sJuR-n6Y

the latest current link to the game is : https://s3.amazonaws.com/unrealtournament/ShippedBuilds/%2B%2BUT%2BRelease-Next-CL-3525360/UnrealTournament-Client-XAN-3525360-Linux.zip

they now have a epic games login that greets you at the start but I don't think it works yet. but you can play offline.

If someone figures out loging in to epic I'll mark that as answer.

EDIT : this no longer works for multiplayer you now have to use the windows version (HEROIC launcher to play multiplayer)